# iframe action is opening one window. i don't want to open that window

Tags: javascript, iframe

code is attached below: i am targetting my form to iframe then i am submitting my form then after this again i am calling one javascript method. but this form submittion is opening new blank window with url. i don't want that. what i have to do??

```
var addForm = $id("addUserVoiceForm");
    document.getElementById("hUploadFile").value=uploadFile;
    addForm.target=$id("uploadFrame");
    addForm.action="uploadVoice.action";//"?subVoiceDef.uploadFile="+uploadFile
    addForm.submit();
    $("#uploadFrame").hide();
    addForm.target="_parent";
    setTimeout(function() {
    afterUpload()
    },1000);
```

Comment: You are setting `target` twice. Maybe remove the second one.

Answer (score -1):

use `_self` instead of `_parent` as your target

Comment: I think that doesn't submit the form to the iframe.